SSRS report files creation within a Parallel.ForEachAsync don't have filenames matching their content on C# .NET 8. Could someone explain the cause?
In order to obtain a faster file generation from SSRS, I've created a Parallel.ForEachAsync code to split among 4 threads then: do some database queries, followed by SSRS requests to generate reports and finally write the result bytes into the hard disk. But for some reason, the filename isn't matching the contents of the created file. The filename is built based on some values from the same parameters used to request the report generation on SSRS.
The first curious thing is, when generating a single file everything goes fine and the filename matches the content of the corresponding file what makes me think it could be some issue caused by the parallel threads, one is .
I'm including only a sketch with the main lines of the code for the file generation using Parallel.ForeEchAsync for simplicity reasons:
public async Task ProcessReportOnParallelAsync( PocoClass pocoObj )
{
    List<People> people = (await this.PeopleRepository.RetrieveAllInvolved( pocoObj.Params )).ToList();
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync( people, new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, async ( personPoco, token ) => 
    {
        var personDetail = await this.PersonDetailsRepository( personPoco.Id, personPoco.CompanyId );
        if( personDetail.ShouldGenerateReport )
        {
            await Report.GenerateAsync( personPoco );
        }

    });
}

public async static Task GenerateAsync( PocoClass pocoObj )
{
    //setup all SSRS object configuration to request the report generation
    var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient( httpBinding, new EndpointAddress(SSRSReportExecutionUrl));
    // ...
    
    // Finally
    await rsExec.SetExecutionParameterAsync( null, null, reportParams, "en-us" );
    const string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar><DeviceInfo>";
    var response await rsExec.RenderAsync( new RenderRequest(null, null, "EXCELOPENXML", deviceInfo));
    var byteResults = response.Result;
    string filename = $@"{pocoObj.Id}_{pocoObj.Name}_{pocoObj.Company}";
    string filepath = $@"{this.FolderPathForFileGeneration}\{filename}";

    var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    await fs.WriteAsync( byteResults);
    fs.Close();
}

The second curious thing is that I've created a very similar code before (which was the base code for this) for another context/SSRS report in the same project. The only difference (excluding the parameters and classes involved) regarding the Parallel and SSRS instructions is the RenderRequest parameter, instead of RenderRequest(null, null, "EXCELOPENXML", deviceInfo) the other one generates PDFs: RenderRequest(null, null, "PDF", deviceInfo), everything goes well on it, the filenames correspond to their respective contents.
So I'd like to understand what could be happening that I didn't figure it out: the stored procedure involved on the report generation, or a difference on configuration between the two SSRS Reports, or something else, I don't know.
Also if there is a solution or another suggestion or better approach for this implementation.
Thanks in advance!

Are you sure that the objects you are using in parallel, like the unknown object rsExec, can be safely used by multiple threads concurrently without synchronization? Unless the documentation states explicitly that they are, you should assume that they are not.

The rsExec object is from class ReportExecutionServiceSoap. Actually, I don't know if they can be used but on each run a new instance is created then it is used to build the Soap request for SSRS, in my understanding it should run independent. But I will take a look on the documentation. Thanks!

It seems a team member solved the issue migrating the parallel logic code to the method responsible for calling the SSRS.
Once I review the code I'll post the update.
